# Suppress quote character in bash completion

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete

I am adding bash completion for some parameters of a query that users can enter on the command line to a script. Something like:

```
foo.py 'select abc(), def
```

Here I am completing the column names `abc()` and `def`. The problem that I am facing is that bash is automatically adding the ending single quote which is a hindrance to users. They might want to continue writing the query. Note that I need to use the single quotes while accepting the query as the query can contain parenthesis.

For example,

```
foo.py 'select ab<TAB>
```

should result in:

```
foo.py 'select abc(
```

instead of:

```
foo.py 'select abc('
```

My completion function returns `select abc(` but it seems that bash is inserting the extra closing quote that I want to get rid of. Any ideas how to do this?

Completion function used:

```
_egg_autocomplete_()
{
    case "$COMP_CWORD" in
      2)
          readarray -t COMPREPLY < <( ./suggest.py order $2 )
          ;;
    esac
}
```

`suggest.py` contains the actual code which prints suggested completions one per line. The suggestions can contain spaces in them.

I found the following at https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS but was unable to make it work:

> j.  New application variable, rl_completion_suppress_quote, settable
>   by an    application completion function.  If set to non-zero,
>   readline does not    attempt to append a closing quote to a completed
>   word.

I added the following line to my `~/.inputrc` file but it didn't cause any difference:

```
set rl_completion_suppress_quote 1
```

Bash version used: GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: Welcome to the site!  **(1)** Would you please edit your question to include the code for your completion routine?  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about asking questions that will attract effective answers.   **(2)** What bash version are you using (`bash --version`)?  I note the variable you mention was added in bash 3.0.

Comment: What did you try that did not work?

Comment: I added `set rl_completion_suppress_quote 1` to my `~/.inputrc` but it didn't help. I have edited the question to include this info, the completion function and the bash version.